# Why can't the api health kit connect to com.apple.healthkit?

Tags: nativescript, healthkit

I am collecting an app that should be able to get data from the ios Health app

Included in the application id the HealthKit feature, added nativescript-health-data plugin

When running for debugging via usb, Error `"Domain = com.apple.healthkit Code = 4" Missing com.apple.developer.healthkit entitlement.` is written to the log, when trying to authorize and download data, nothing happens.

Has anyone come across this?

I found a mention that this problem can be solved via xcode, but I don’t understand how to open the application in it.

Comment: open the .xcodeProj file from app/platform/ios folder

Comment: I work in windows 10 and there is no such file in the project. I understand that to edit it you need to work in mac? And run not a cloud build, but a local one?

Comment: so are you using sidekick to build ?

Comment: Yes. I took a long time to deal with the generation of certificates and in the end it turned out to be the simplest solution for building an application for iphone

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to enable `HealthKit` capability on your application identifier at developer portal. You might have to download the updated provisional profiles too.

Create an entitlements file with your app name (`${YourAppName}.entitlements`) at `/App_Resources/iOS` and paste the content below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>com.apple.developer.healthkit</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.developer.healthkit.access</key>
    <array/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Now open `/App_Resources/iOS/build.xcconfig` and add this line,

```
CODE_SIGN_ENTITLEMENTS = ${YourAppName}/${YourAppName}.entitlements
```

Replace `${YourAppName}` with your app name, now try a clean build.

Comment: Thanks for the help.
To add the entitlements file, I added the plugin `nativescript-custom-entitlements`.
In the file $ {YourAppName} / $ {YourAppName} .entitlements I added the text plist that you sent above.
After that, the error really disappeared, but when you try to connect, a notification appears
```Requesting authorization to share <private>, read <private>
Connection to "com.apple.healthd.server" invalidated```
Tell me, please, with what it can be connected.
I still run via nativescript sidekick on a real device via usb debugging (iphone 5s)

Comment: Plugin
https://github.com/Essent/nativescript-custom-entitlements

But I have now corrected the error output and write the following information to the log when I try to log in:
```Error: NSHealthUpdateUsageDescription must be set in the following forms: HKQuantityTypeIdentifierHeight, HKQuantityTypeIdentifierBodyMass```

I am now looking for information on these errors.

Comment: Brought in line with this file https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/nativescript-health-data/blob/master/src/platforms/ios/Info.plist, now I restart. Hope that helps. True, thanks for the help.

Comment: Cool, Eddy might have missed to document it, glad you figured it out.